# Python 2D NumPy array comprehension

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension

I am new to NumPy. I have a 2-D NumPy array containing floating point values. I wish to get the index of those elements which are greater than 70 % of a certain value, say **t** ,in the entire matrix.

`output = [(1,2),(4,7),(7,1)]` 
meaning **arr[1][2]**, **arr[4][7]** and **arr[7][1]** have values greater than 70% of **t**

Using 2 loops to get job done is a fairly uncomplicated way. What is the most Pythonic way of getting it done (list comprehension etc.) ? Please point out any duplicates. Thanks !

Comment: Numpy's [where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) sounds relevant here, give it a look.

Comment: Give the rest of that sample case, including your loops.  Any by the way, for `numpy` we normally index: `arr[1,2]`, not `arr[1][2]`.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, did not get your point. Sample case as in ? I just have a 2-D array I wish to traverse.

Comment: Note: frequently, computing the actual indices is unnecessary overhead. Most calls to `where` I see around here can simply be removed without affecting the program's behavior, and the code will run faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example:

```
In [76]: arr=np.arange(20, dtype=float).reshape(4,5)

In [77]: arr
Out[77]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
       [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.]])
```

A boolean index that can select values from the array

```
In [79]: arr>15
Out[79]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [80]: arr[arr>15]
Out[80]: array([ 16.,  17.,  18.,  19.])
```

Indexes where the condition is true, which can also be used to select elements

```
In [81]: I=np.nonzero(arr>15)

In [82]: I
Out[82]: (array([3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int32), array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32))

In [83]: arr[I]
Out[83]: array([ 16.,  17.,  18.,  19.])
```

Or turn the index tuple into a list of pairs

```
In [84]: list(zip(*I))
Out[84]: [(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]

In [87]: [arr[j] for j in zip(*I)]
Out[87]: [16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0]
```